# java: mutual exclusion for a global date used by more thread

Tags: java, multithreading

hi mate i have a global date in my class,
this date is used and modified by two thread, i need to solve the problem of mutual exclusion for this date. i m non expert in java, in c is simple,  at example:

```
lock(...)
use/modified global date
unlock(....)
```

I need the corrispondent in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approach you can use:

1) Use synchronized keywords:

```
synchronized(theGlobalDate) {
  // do whatever modification you want
}
```

This is the basics in Java world.

2) In Java 5, there is new set of concurrent library, you can use locks for things you do somehting similar to what you did in C

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

.....

public void foo() { 
  lock.lock();
  try {
    // do whatever modification you want
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: in some example , some programmator use synchronized(Myclass.class) { } what is the difference ?

Comment: Synchronizing on the class object is the same as a static synchronized  method.  It is the difference between locking on the _instance_ and a global lock of which there is one per ClassLoader.  I would recommend creating a `static` lock object instead.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, use a `synchronized` block:

```
Object dateLock = new Object(); // globally visible lock, declare it 
                                // next to your date object

//...

synchronized(dateLock) {
   // modify date
}
```

The above is sufficient for two threads. For more complicated scenarios, like when reading is done by multiple threads often and writing is seldom, look into [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: normally in such case, we synchronized on that date object instead of having a separate object as lock.

Comment: in some example , some programmator use  

synchronized(Myclass.class) {
}    what is the difference ?

Comment: @Adrian Shum: That is not advisable. If the object itself uses some internal synchronization then your program could break since you are taking the lock externally.

Comment: @dario frongi: That is synchronization on the class itself. I prefer to use a separate object since it's more clear what data I'm protecting.